# Angular POST JSON Request Return 417 Expectation Failed

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript

I have an application that send json data to server, and return 417 Expectation Failed. What is that error?

I already search the answer, but on Angular case, there is no answer yet.

```
findAllcodePrefix(word: String) {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.baseHttp.post(this.apiUrl.concat('findListCodePrefix/'), { find: word }, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
  }
```

Output 417 Expectation Failed

Comment: can you please share your server logs.

Comment: and also the code of `component` where u are making this `http` call

Answer (score 1):

4xx series error's indicate your request is set up incorrectly in some way. This would indicate the server hosting the service has some restrictions/requirements they want in your request. 
I would suggest checking the service's documentation and their header requirements, size requirements, etc and make sure your request matches their requirements.

also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect
or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/417